# App crashes on [[AKMicrophone alloc]initWith:[[AVAudioFormat alloc]initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 channels:2]]

Tags: ios, audiokit

App crashes while initializing AKMicrohone.

> - Objective-C
> - AudioKit :4.8

```
-(void)setupFrequencyDetector{
    @try {
        AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true;
        //self.mic = [[AKMicrophone alloc]initWith:[[AVAudioFormat alloc]initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:44100 channels:2 interleaved:true]];
        self.mic = [[AKMicrophone alloc]initWith:[[AVAudioFormat alloc]initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 channels:2]];
        self.tracker = [[AKFrequencyTracker alloc]init:self.mic hopSize:4096 peakCount:20];
        self.silence = [[AKBooster alloc]init:self.tracker gain:0];
        AudioKit.output = self.silence;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.description);
    } @finally {}
}
```

> Exception :required condition is false: format.sampleRate ==
>   hwFormat.sampleRate AudioKit+StartStop.swift:start():34:No output node
>   has been set yet, no processing will happen.

Comment: Its very hard to definitely give you an answer when you're providing just one method. The error seems to be implying that you never set output, so is `setupFrequencyDetector` even being called before AudioKit is started? Would be best to provide a GitHub link with a project that exhibits this bug.

Comment: There is nothing else. 1.Install 'AudioKit' in Objective-C only project. 2. Import AudioKit. 3. Define properties for "AKMicrophone, AKFrequencyTracker & AKBooster". 4. Call this function in viewDidAppear(:).

Answer (score 3):

By setting the audio format and sample rate resolved the issue.

```
AVAudioFormat *audioFormat = [AudioKit.engine.inputNode inputFormatForBus:0];
AKSettings.sampleRate = audioFormat.sampleRate;
self.mic = [[AKMicrophone alloc]initWith:audioFormat];
```

Updated function:

```
-(void)setupFrequencyDetector{
@try {
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true;
    AVAudioFormat *audioFormat = [AudioKit.engine.inputNode inputFormatForBus:0];
    AKSettings.sampleRate = audioFormat.sampleRate;
    self.mic = [[AKMicrophone alloc]initWith:audioFormat];
    self.tracker = [[AKFrequencyTracker alloc]init:self.mic hopSize:4096 peakCount:20];
    self.silence = [[AKBooster alloc]init:self.tracker gain:0];
    AudioKit.output = self.silence;
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.description);
} @finally {}}
```